# Cakephp display all number of comments of post in a single page

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I want to display all comments along with all posts in a single page.For eg : I have 3 comments for POST A,2 comments for post B and so on.

It should look like this :
POST A - 3 Comments
POST B - 2 Comments and so on

So for this I have coded this :

```
  $result = $this->Comment->find('all',array('fields'=>array('Comment.post_id','Comment.comments'),'group'=>'Comment.post_id'));
  pr($a);exit;
  $this->set('a',$a);
```

The array I got is this

```
           Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [Comment] => Array
            (
                [post_id] => 1
                [comments] => Nice Post...Nice Post...Nice Post...
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Comment] => Array
            (
                [post_id] => 3
                [comments] => wow..nice !!! Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
            )

    )

)
```

I have total 3 comments for `post_id = 1`
I want all the three comments come together.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `,'group'=>'Comment.post_id'` from your `find()`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly what you mean, there are a number of ways to do that.

### Find on Post

The question description is:

> want to display all comments along with all posts

For that you'd only need to perform a find on Post, including Comment in the scope of the results. If your associations have been defined correctly that means:

```
$result = $Post->find('all', array(
    'recursive' => 1
));
```

In this case, $result will be of the form:

```
[0] => Array
        (   
            [Post] => Array
                (   
                    [id] => 1
                    [title] => First article
                    [content] => aaa 
                    [created] => 2008-05-18 00:00:00
                )   
            [Comment] => Array
                (   
                    [0] => Array
                        (   
                            [id] => 1
                            [post_id] => 1
                            [author] => Daniel
                            [email] => dan@example.com
                            [website] => http://example.com
                            [comment] => First comment
                            [created] => 2008-05-18 00:00:00
                        )   
                    [1] => Array
                        (   
                            [id] => 2
                            [post_id] => 1
                            [author] => Sam 
                            [email] => sam@example.net
                            [website] => http://example.net
                            [comment] => Second comment
                            [created] => 2008-05-18 00:00:00
                        )   
                )
        )   
[1] => Array
        (   
            [Post] => Array
                (...
```

Instead of using recursive, you can use [the containable behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) to fine-tune the amount of information returned.

### Find on Post - counting comments

To get a list of posts and their comment counts - you need first to understand the sort of query required - e.g.:

```
SELECT
    Post.id, 
    COUNT(Comment.id)
FROM
    posts as Post
LEFT JOIN
    comments as Comment ON (Post.id = Comment.post_id)
GROUP BY
    Post.id
```

Without the join, any post with no comments will not be listed.

There are many ways to execute a query of that kind - here's one:

```
$result = $Post->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Post.id', 
        'COUNT(Comment.id)'
    ),
    'group' => array('Post.id'),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'comments',
            'alias' => 'Comment',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Post.id = Comment.post_id'
            )
        )
    )
));
```

### Use find list

The group query in the question isn't the right structure unless there's an aggregate function used (count, sum, etc.). To get all comments grouped by post id - you can however use [find list](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list):

```
$result = $Comment->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'id',
        'comments',
        'post_id'
    )
));
```

Used in this way the response format will be:

```
$result['post_id']['id']['comment']
```

i.e.:

```
array(
    1 => array(
        aa => 'Nice Post...Nice Post...Nice Post...',
        bb => 'Another comment for post id 1'
    ),
    3 => array(
        cc => 'wow..nice !!! Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting ',
        dd => 'Another comment for post id 3',
        ...
    )
)
```

Comment: Its right but i want in numbers ie., for 1 total 3 post and so on

Comment: added an example of returing posts and comment counts.